# Getting Reflection.Emit codes for a code fragement in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly, reflection.emit

I am creating a type with reflection by using the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3862241/1519458). And I want to add a function to this class (probably using ILGenerator). And in the comment section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1960774/1519458), [Sergey Mirvoda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/127409/sergey-mirvoda) commented that ILGenerator emit commands can be obtained by simply following these steps: ***compile it into assembly and open with reflector, switch to IL view and you will see code that copypastable***

I do not want to decompile so that I can get the lost code. Therefore I am not looking for a decompiler. I am trying to get IL Emit codes for a sample code I currently have. Decompiling might just do the trick. However there may be other solutions and hopefully not requiring third party apps.

I am using VS Ultimate 2013. Is there a way to do this with VS? Or do I need to use third party apps?

Comment: You could use Telerik JustDecompile, for *free*.

Comment: or ILSpy, which comes with source code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A .net disassembler/decompiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578883/a-net-disassembler-decompiler)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the IL opcodes, for example:

```
ldarg.0
conv.i8
dup
mul
ret
```

Then you have several options, including ildasm (included in the Windows SDK), dotPeek's IL viewer or LINQPad's IL tab (all of them gratis).

If you want a tool that automatically generates Reflection.Emit code, e.g.:

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_I8);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Mul);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Then the only one I know of is the ReflectionEmitLanguage add-on to Reflector (which is paid).

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator(v=vs.110).aspx

ILGenerator allows you to do what you show in your second snippet.

Comment: @user9993 Yes, I know. My answer is about how to decompile existing code into code that can be used with `ILGenerator`.